# How to include plugin in maven for test build only?

Tags: maven, testing

I want to add the plugin in the maven project. I want it to be added to build only when I build the project for testing purpose.

I found that `<scope>` can be used for dependency as shown below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback</artifactId>
  <version>0.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

As you can see here `<scope>test</scope>`is used.

I want similar thing for plugin. For example this is my plugin code snipplet

```
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bind</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Based on the docs this plugin is by default bound to `process-classes` which is not in testing ...the question is what you like to achieve? Why not dinging it via executions to the appropriate phase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a profile which you activate in your test builds:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>testing</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>bind</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
   </profile>
</profile>
```

Then you invoke mvn with the parameter `-P testing` to activate your profile:

```
mvn test -P testing
```

In addition to activating a profile manually, profiles can also be activated automatically based on conditions such as the existence of a environment variable or a specific file. You can find more information on this in the [Maven introduction on profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a plugin via executions to a phase:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
      <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.4</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>bind</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The problem I see that [usually this plugin runs](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/bind-mojo.html) in `process-classes` phase which has been done on purpose by the plugin authors..So I don't the request to use it only in the test phase...